# Updating a specific column value in a row inside a datatable from a backing bean based on another column values change

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have  a dialog `<p:dialog id="vpmopopup">` inside that, I have a form `<h:form id="vpmoForm">`,inside that, I have a datatable    `<p:dataTable id="reqTypeDtbl">` and inside this datatable, I have an `<h:selectOneMenu>` and  `<h:inputText >` in **seperate columns in same row.**

I need to render the `<h:inputText >` based on the `<h:selectOneMenu>` ajax event called where I am setting some values in the backing bean to render the `<h:inputText >`  in the sepecific row in the datatable.

I also have an option to add rows and say, when I have added two row, in the seconde row, I am changing the value of the `<h:selectOneMenu>` where its Ajax method is called which in turn should update the `<h:inputText >` from the backing bean.

I tried lot of workaround but nothin seems to work.

Here is the  workaround I tried 

Ajax Call in UI :

```
<p:dataTable id="reqTypeDtbl" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150"
             value="#{systemDetailsBean.vpmoReqDetailslsList}"
             rowIndexVar="index" var="vpmoReqDtlRow"
             rowKey="#{vpmoReqDtlRow.reqTypeName}">
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItems value="#{systemDetailsBean.vpmoTSSList}" 
                       var="tss" itemLabel="#{tss.label}" itemValue="#{tss.value}" />
        <p:ajax listener="#{systemDetailsBean.getTssId}"    process="@this"  
                partialSubmit="true" />
        <f:param name="rowidno" value="#{index}" required="true" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</p:dataTable>
```

Ajax Implementation in Bean :

```
public void getTssId(AjaxBehaviorEvent evt) {
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    int index = Integer.parseInt(params.get("rowidno"));
    String selected = vpmoReqDetailslsList.get(index).getTssReqId();

    //I could get the correct rowindex and the selected value using the above code.
    if (selected.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        vpmoEditFlag = false;
        vpmoReqDetailslsList.get(index).setTssReqId("Y");
        System.out.println("Yes  valuve >>" + vpmoReqDetailslsList.get(index).getTssReqId());

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("vpmoForm:reqTypeDtbl:" + index + ":except");
        //I am trying to update the inputtext for the selected row in the datatable from above
    } else {
        vpmoReqDetailslsList.get(index).setTssReqId("N");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("vpmoForm:reqTypeDtbl:" + index + ":except");
        //I am trying to update the inputtext for the selected row in the datatable from above
    }
}
```

The code for rendering  `<h:inputText >`

```
<h:inputText value="#{vpmoReqDtlRow.exceptionNum}" id="javax.faces.ViewState"  style="width:100%"
                                rendered="#{systemDetailsBean.vpmoEditFlag eq  true and  vpmoReqDtlRow.tssReqId eq  'Y'}" />
```

How can I render the `<h:inputText>` from the backing bean for a specific row.I mean,  I need to update a specific row which is inside a data table and the data table is inside a form .

The below approach is not working for me

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("vpmoForm:reqTypeDtbl:" + index + ":except");
```

Is there any other option for this to update the only the component inside the datatable which I have highlighted in the screenshot?

Any suggestions will be really helpful to resolve this issue.

Adding screen shot for further ref:

[image]

Comment: What is the version of Primefaces that you are using?

Comment: I am using primefaces-3.4.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the problem and the problem here is that you won't be able to update a not rendered component. If you change it to disabled you will see that everything work as expected.

A good way to update the input without messing up with your layout is wrapping it with a `<h:panelGrupo>` as I did here:

```
<h:form id="vpmoForm">
    <p:dataTable id="reqTypeDtbl" value="#{systemDetailsBean.vpmoReqDetailslsList}"
                 var="vpmoReqDtlRow" rowIndexVar="index">
        <p:column >
            <h:selectOneMenu id="slct" value="#{vpmoReqDtlRow.tssReqId}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{systemDetailsBean.getTssId}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{systemDetailsBean.vpmoTSSList}" 
                               var="tss" itemLabel="#{tss.label}" itemValue="#{tss.value}" />
                <f:param name="rowidno" value="#{index}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:panelGroup id="except">
                <h:inputText value="#{vpmoReqDtlRow.exceptionNum}" style="width:100%"
                             rendered="#{systemDetailsBean.vpmoEditFlag and vpmoReqDtlRow.tssReqId eq  'Y'}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**Note** that in your getTssId you are setting the vpmoEditFlag to false every time you set the 
tssReqId to Y. This is probably a mistake.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public void getTssId(AjaxBehaviorEvent evt) {

    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    int index = Integer.parseInt(params.get("rowidno"));
    String selected = vpmoReqDetailslsList.get(index).getTssReqId();

    //I could get the correct rowindex and the selected value using the above code.
    if (selected.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        vpmoEditFlag = true;
        System.out.println("Yes  valuve >>" + vpmoReqDetailslsList.get(index).getTssReqId());
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("vpmoForm:reqTypeDtbl:" + index + ":except");
        //I am trying to update the inputtext for the selected row in the datatable from above
    } else {
        vpmoEditFlag = false;
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("vpmoForm:reqTypeDtbl:" + index + ":except");
        //I am trying to update the inputtext for the selected row in the datatable from above
    }
}
```

Comment: :You solution works fine!!.Thank you so much.But what is does it mean by "you won't be able to update a not rendered component." ?.The  <h:inputText> is having a rendered attribute and whats might be the reason why  its not rendering ? Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Primefaces updates a component based on their id on the html page. If the first input is not rendered and you ask primefaces to update it, you will notice that a request will be sent to update the html component with id equals to **vpmoForm:reqTypeDtbl:0:except** and as it is not present in the html, the request will be silently ignored.

Comment: :Understood ! But I am passsing the specific index of the datatable to backing bean.But Still it won't work to update a specific row ?.Sorry for bothering you a lot.Just curious to understand the scenario.